# Google Chrome and Firefox - different ordering of divs

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, z-index

It's simple: http://jsfiddle.net/urgT8/

On Chrome, the ABC buttons are above the `.moreinfo` divs, in Firefox, they are below. Why is it happening and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Firefox is doing the right thing.

It's also broken in Chrome once `-webkit-filter` is removed: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/urgT8/2/

Evidently, Chrome is only showing the ABC buttons on top because of the `-webkit-filter`. Whether or not this is a bug, I can't say.

Anyway, you can fix the problem in all browsers with `position: relative` on `.info .dugmici`.

Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/urgT8/1/